# While loop not looping - Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

A while loop in my code is not looping.

I've tried ensuring the while loop would loop but no loop was executed.

```
#Name_Input
login = 1
while login == 1:
    print("Enter the username and password \n")
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    if password and username != "cameron" and "123":
        print("\nWrong username or password... \nTry Again...")
        login = 1
```

I am expecting the loop to go back to the login when the login details are entered incorrectly.

Comment: The condition in your `if` doesn't work as you expect. You need to do something like `if condition_1 or condition_2`

Comment: Why not use boolean value for login?

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude because  `1` is a boolean value. Actually all objects in Python have a boolean value, the  `bool` type was a later (and highly debated FWIW) addition.

Comment: @owninggreendragsdude also the OP may have a need for more than possible 2 values here (I fail to imagine why but we only have a short excerpt of the real code) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
login = 1
while login == 1:
    print("Enter the username and password \n")
    username = str(input("Username: "))
    password = str(input("Password: "))
    if username  ==  "cameron" and   password == "123":
        login=2
    else:
        print("\nWrong username or password... \nTry Again...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if syntax:

```
login = 1
while login == 1:
    print("Enter the username and password \n")
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")
    if password !=  "123" or username != "cameron":
        print("\nWrong username or password... \nTry Again...")
        login = 1
    else:
        login = -1
```

Comment: The condition still won't work as the OP expects (I believe). Please read up on [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). And read the message being printed, it contains the right logic. :)